# Configurable product - show individually

Tags: configurable-product

i have problem with displaying configurable products. We are using Magento 1.9.3.6 (but will be migrating to Magento 2.4.3 soon.

I started creating configurable products, everything is working OK - I have product displayed, click on configurable swatches (e. g. color, size), but problem is that after clickin to this swatch, it doesn´t go to this product, only swatch is selected. The type of behavior I am looking for is, that when customer clicks on one of the swatch (let´s say blue T-shirt), he is redirected to blue T-shirt URL with that product. Reason is simple - we have multiple images for every color and this way we are not able to display multiple images, but just one. Same way for example zalando has this https://www.zalando.sk/calvin-klein-golf-3-pack-zakladne-tricko-khakinavywhite-ck442d00j-n11.html

I was thinking of doing this by having those variants (products in swatches) to be displayed in catalog (instead of do not show individually), but this then creates problem as these products have no images.

Also, I have question, how can this be done on any simple product already created before?

Do you have any idea how this can be done in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Configurable products work like that. The point of configurable products is that You have one page for multiple products.

I guess, the functionality You are looking for is (it should be also easier to implement):
Display Child (simple) product's Galery (instead of the Configurable), whenever customer change / choose swatch on Configurable Product Page.

But are You looking for solution for M1.9 or M2.4 ?
Anyway, at this point, You should be able to find a solution much easier (if that solution is sufficient).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Yes, I suppose this is what we are looking for. I am doing this on 1.9 now, but as we will be migrating to 2.4, it will need to work there as well, so it must be Magento´s built in functionality. 

Where can I set to display child product´s gallery? I do not see such an option in settings. I can´t beleive Magento doesn´t have this function built-in. Is this built-in in M2 maybe?

Comment: As far as I remember, there is no option like that in M1.9. But You should be able to find solution for that. For M2 You just have to check if base behavior works for You. Please, keep in mind, that some configurations related to that behavior are directly in Attribute config - for swatch attributes.